# CSS responsive menu with search box

Tags: html, css

How do i display the icons in the right place as shown in the following image? :

[image: sample]

### HTML Code

```html
    <header id="logo"></header>

    <div class="navbar" id="nav">
      <a href="https://klia2.co" class="active">Home</a>
      <a href="../facilities/index.htm">Facilities</a>
      <a href="../airlines/index.htm">Airlines Offices</a>
       <input type="text" placeholder="Search..">
         <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>  </div>
    
</div>

    <script>
        function myFunction() {
          var x = document.getElementById("nav");
          if (x.className === "navbar") {
            x.className += " responsive";
          } else {
            x.className = "navbar";
          }
        }
        
        
</script>
```

### CSS Code

```css
.navbar {
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #0000ff;
       

      }

    
    .navbar a {
      float: left;
      display: block;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 14px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 17px;
      height:18px;
         

    }

    .active {
      background-color: #0033CC;
      color: white;
      

    }

    .navbar .icon {
      display: none;
      

    }

    
    .navbar a:hover, input:hover {
      background-color: #dddddd;
      color: black;
      

    }
    
    /* CSS for search box */
    .navbar input[type=text] {
      float: right;
      padding: 12px;
      border: none;
      margin-top: 3px;
      margin-right: 5px;    
      
     
}


    
    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      .navbar a, .navbar input {
        display: none;
        
      }
      .navbar a.icon {
        float: left;
        display: block;
        
      }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      .navbar.responsive {position:relative;}
      .navbar.responsive .icon {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        
      }
      .navbar.responsive a {
        float: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
        
      }
      
      .navbar.responsive input { 
        float: none;
        display: block;
        width: 90%;
        padding: 12px;
        border: 2px solid black;
        text-align: left;
        
    
      }
      
    }
```

Note: For the search box I need to make it as a HTML form, and the font awesome search icon to be a submit button, not just normal HTML icon tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To **achieve** this just **update** your **HTML** with following code

```
<header id="logo"></header>
<div class="navbar" id="nav">
  <a href="https://klia2.co" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="../facilities/index.htm">Facilities</a>
  <a href="../airlines/index.htm">Airlines Offices</a>
  <form class="search-box">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search..">
    <button type="submit" class="search-icon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    
  </form>
    
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>  
</div>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("nav");
      
      console.log(barIcon)
      if (x.className === "navbar") {
        x.className += " responsive";
        var barIcon = document.getElementsByClassName('fa-bars')[0];
        barIcon.classList.add("fa-times");
        barIcon.classList.remove("fa-bars");
      } else {
        var closeIcon = document.getElementsByClassName('fa-times')[0];
        closeIcon.classList.remove("fa-times");
        closeIcon.classList.add("fa-bars");
        x.className = "navbar";
      }
    }  
</script>
```

and Your **CSS** with the following

```
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #0000ff;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  height:18px;
     

}
.active {
  background-color: #0033CC;
  color: white;
  

}
.navbar .icon {
  display: none;
  

}
.navbar a:hover, input:hover {
  background-color: #dddddd;
  color: black;
}
/* CSS for search box */
.navbar .search-box {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 3px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  display: flex;
}
.navbar .search-box input {
  padding: 12px;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}
.navbar .search-box button {
  color: #999;
  border: navajowhite;
  padding: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .navbar a, .navbar .search-box, .navbar .search-icon {
    display: none;
    
  }
  .navbar a.icon {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .navbar.responsive {position:relative;}
  .navbar.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    
  }
  .navbar.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    
  }
  
  .navbar.responsive .search-box { 
    float: none;
    display: flex;
    width: 90%;
    padding: 4%;
    border: 2px solid black;
  }
  .navbar.responsive .search-icon{
    display: flex;
  }
}
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Hi there are millions of ways to reach this structure. I usually use MDBOOTSTAP . But if you are looking for a raw html css, you can use the relative/absolute capability. This answer assumes that you have font awsome installed for the search icon:

```
<style>
.position-relative{
   position:relative;
 }
 .position-absolute{
position:absolute;
}
.w-100{
 width:100%;
}
.search-container{
top:0.5rem;
right:1rem;
z-index:99999;
}
</style>

    <div class="navbar" id="nav">
      <a href="https://klia2.co" class="active">Home</a>
      <a href="../facilities/index.htm">Facilities</a>
      <a href="../airlines/index.htm">Airlines Offices</a>
        <div class="position-relative w-100">
           <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." class="w-100 p-3 m-0">
            <div class="position-absolute search-container">
              <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a> 
             </div>
```